# Put the "$message" inside the table in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a problem i want to put the `$message` inside the table that is a equivalent as a "Search not found".

Here is my picture outside the table [`$message =` Search not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTbRZ.png)

**View:**

```
 <div class="z table-responsive" >
            <table class=" table table-hover"  >


                 <thead >
                             <tr >

                                   <th>ID Number</th>
                                   <th>First name</th>
                                   <th>Middle name</th>
                                   <th>Last name</th>
                                   <th>Sex</th>

                           </tr>
                      </thead>

   <?php if ( isset($message) ){
         echo  $message;

   } else{  foreach($results as $row){
        ?>

    <tbody>
          <tr>


                  <td><?php echo $row-> Idnumber ?></td>
                  <td class="text-capitalize "><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Lastname ?></td>
                   <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Sex?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('viewstudentinalpha/viewspecific/'.$row->Id) ?>" class="btn btn-info " style="font-size: 18px;" type="submit" name="submit" role="button">Option</a>

                             </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>




    <?php }} ?>




            </tbody>

            </table>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong end tags.

> This will **print `Search not found` inside the table with `colspan 5` and `center aligned`**
>
> ***Note*: Most of time we check where `foreach` value is empty (`$results`). But in your case you are checking some thing else (`$message`).**

**Changes**

```
<tr>  <!-- Changed -->
    <td colspan="5" align="center"><?php echo  $message; ?> </td>
</tr>
```

---

`if ( isset($message) ){` is changed to `if (!empty($message)){`

**Final code**

```
<div class="z table-responsive" >
    <table class=" table table-hover"  >
        <thead >
            <tr >
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Middle name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
            if (!empty($message)) # improved
            {
                ?>
                <tr> # Changed
                    <td colspan="5" align="center"><?php echo  $message; ?> </td>
                </tr>
                <?php           
            } 
            else
            {  
                foreach($results as $row)
                {
                    ?>              
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row-> Idnumber ?></td>
                            <td class="text-capitalize "><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
                            <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
                            <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Lastname ?></td>
                            <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Sex?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="<?php echo site_url('viewstudentinalpha/viewspecific/'.$row->Id) ?>" class="btn btn-info " style="font-size: 18px;" type="submit" name="submit" role="button">
                                    Option
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php 
                }
            } 
            ?>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

---

**Edit 01**

**In Controller**

```
function search_keyword() 
{ 
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in'); 
    $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username']; 
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword'); 
    $data['results'] = $this->model_adminlogin->search($keyword); 
    $this->load->view('result_view',$data); 
}
```

**In View**

Alter your if like this.

Copy all codes i have added in above for your view. and only change this few lines.

```
<?php 
if (!empty($results)) # Change
{
    ?>
    <tr> # Change
        <td colspan="5" align="center"> Search not found </td> # Change
    </tr>
    <?php           
} 
else
{
```

Comment: this is my controller     function search_keyword()
    {
        
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
           
            $data['Username'] = $session_data['Username'];
        $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
     
          $data['results']    =   $this->model_adminlogin->search($keyword);
     
      if ( empty($data['results']) ) 
    {
             $data['message'] = 'Search not found';

    }
   $this->load->view('result_view',$data);
}

Comment: @FreezingBernUchiha ok will give best solution for you. hold on

Comment: thank you sir even i disturb you so much thank you sir! @Abdulla

Comment: @FreezingBernUchiha happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an issue with CodeIgniter so much as your code.  What you are trying to do with the code is to put the message between the `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, and not in any table tags.

This is the same as trying to put it between rows in a table, and therefore gets interpreted as not being part of the table, and drawn outside of the table as a result.

If you put the message into the `<tbody>`, it will go in the right place, so you can do:

```
<?php if ( isset($message) ){
         echo  "<tbody><tr><td colspan='5'>" . $message . "</td></tr></tbody>";

   }....
```

Comment: Thank you sir, @gabe3886

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
<tbody>
 <?php 
 if ( isset($result ) 
// or if (!isset($message)) //depend on your code
     {  
       foreach($results as $row){
 ?>

      <tr> 
              <td><?php echo $row-> Idnumber ?></td>
              <td class="text-capitalize "><?php echo $row -> Firstname ?></td>
               <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row->Middlename ?></td>
               <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Lastname ?></td>
               <td class="text-capitalize"><?php echo $row-> Sex?></td>
               <td>
                   <a href="<?php echo site_url('viewstudentinalpha/viewspecific/'.$row->Id) ?>" class="btn btn-info " style="font-size: 18px;" type="submit" name="submit" role="button">Option</a>
              </td>
     </tr>

  <?php }}
   else 
   //or elseif(isset($message)) //depend on your code
   {
         echo $message; ?>
   }
 </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```